# Участника забанили на 100 лет. И это не шутка

Tags: поддержка, блокировка, модераторский-произвол

Есть [участник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6953/spoilt). У него в профиле написано, что срок его блокировки истечёт в 2121 году. Может, не стоит банить участника на 100 лет?
И имелся в виду 2021 год? А то я даже представить не могу, за какие грехи можно такое получить .

[image: бан на 100 лет]

Comment: Ссылка в профиле намекает, что его взломали и использовали для спама. Если заброшенный профиль взламывают спамеры и владелец не сбрасывает пароль, вечный бан - единственный выход.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight  а где ссылка? У него в профиле только "Хочу учиться..."

Comment: Обычная ссылка в профиле, под надписью "Участник в течение..."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Модераторы могут назначать блокировку сроком не более одного года. Если кто-то заблокирован на больший срок, то эта блокировка назначается сотрудниками Stack Exchange и распространяется по всей сети сайтов. Вечной блокировки не предусмотрено, поэтому используются вот такие "вековые".